# MVC - How to refresh HTML table after setting a value in <select> element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

From what I understand, the Razor foreach statement used in a HTML table in a View iterates through the items found in an IEnumerable which is declared as a @model at the top of the View file, and that @model comes from a Controller returning the View with that IEnumerable as an argument for it's Model parameter.

I am not sure if my logic is good here - I am trying to replace that IEnumerable with another one returned from a Controller Action which takes a value as a parameter to selectively fill the IEnumerable based on that value. This value is passed as an {id} through jQuery after the value of an HTML select element is changed. After replacing the IEnumerable I could reload the table using jQuery and the @foreach iterating through the new IEnumerable would display the results needed based on the selected value in the HTML select element.

However, I am not sure how to do this. I have been trying various methods I could think of or find on StackOverflow as solutions to similar problems, no luck.

I am now stuck at this point without any idea where to go.

**HTML:**

```
@model IEnumerable<TrgovinaMVC.Models.racun>

...

<select class="selectpicker" id="selektor" data-style="btn-primary" onchange="TypeChanged(this)">
      <option>Gotovinski</option>
      <option>Virman</option>
</select>

...

<div id="tabela">
    <table class="table table-hover">

...

<tbody>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
          <tr>

...
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function TypeChanged(element) {
    var val = $(element).val();
    $("#tabela").load("/racuns/Reload/" + val);
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Reload(string id)
{
    List<racun> list = new List<racun>();
    foreach (racun r in db.racuns)
    {
        if (r.tipracuna == id)
            list.Add(r);
    }
    return View(list);
}
```

Please point me to the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to fix your problem

1. To reload the entire page in TypeChanged() fucntion
2. To create a partial view and load the table alone from that - suggessted

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Reload()
{
    return View();
}


public ActionResult _ReloadTable(string id)
{
    List<racun> list = new List<racun>();
    foreach (racun r in db.racuns)
    {
        if (r.tipracuna == id)
            list.Add(r);
    }
    return PartialView(list);
}
```

In Reload.cshtml - keep the dropdown code alone

**Reload.cshtml**

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="selektor" data-style="btn-primary" onchange="TypeChanged(this)">
      <option>Gotovinski</option>
      <option>Virman</option>
</select>

<div id="tabela">


</div>
<script>

function TypeChanged(element) {
    var val = $(element).val();
    $("#tabela").load("/racuns/_ReloadTable/" + val);

</script>
```

**_ReloadTable.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<TrgovinaMVC.Models.racun>

<table class="table table-hover">

...

<tbody>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
          <tr>
```

On dropdown change event, partial view will be loaded every time and table data will be updated based on value selected in dropdown

Comment: The second method works exactly like I imagined. After reading the solution, I managed to learn more about partial views and now I understand their use-case better. Thank you.